# Query Ranges in an X++ Batch Class

Tags: axapta, x++, dynamics-ax-2009

Can anyone tell me which method to put a Query Range into for a class which is batchable?

I have a sample batch class, which runs fine. It retrieves all the records in the Sales Table. I know that I need to add a QueryBuildRange object somewhere, then set the value of the range to a particular value (e.g. Sales ID = 00123456), but I'm not sure what method to put it in (main? Run? QueryRun? InitQuery?)

Thanks for your help!

Comment: Depends on the logic of the class and the methods you have. Is it a standard class? In which  method perform your query?

Answer (score 1):

It depends on what you're wanting to do, but in AX 2009 for batch, you can look at `InventCountCreate_Base` for an example of how Microsoft does it.

Specifically these two methods:

- `\Classes\InventCountCreate_Base\new`
- `\Classes\InventCountCreate_Base\initQueryRun`

Microsoft does it several different ways. You can see an alternative method in `WMSShipmentReservationBatch` in these two methods:

- `\Classes\WMSShipmentReservationBatch\main`
- `\Classes\WMSShipmentReservationBatch\buildQueryRun`

Comment: Also, you can change the query using the Parameters button in "View Task" of the batch job.